# MognoDb c# driver 2.0 serialize query

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have a defenition of generic `FilterDefenition` - `FilterDefinition<T> matchfilter`. How can i convert it into `MongoDb` query ? When i try to get `JSON` i recieve

``` "{ \"_t\" : \"AndFilterDefinition``1\" }" ```

how to get a real query ?